# Use list for items in dropdown button in flutter

Tags: list, flutter

I want to use list(names) for items in dropdown button in flutter.
When open dropdown shows one item with all of list but i want it shows one by one of items in list (names).
my code is:

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetStateFrom extends State<MyStatefulWidgetFrom> {
  String dropdownValue = 'select...' ;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: LoginApi.pes(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData) {
          List<String> names = new List();
          final rep = snapshot.data;
          dropdownValue = 'select...';
          for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            names.add(rep[j]['name']);
          }
            return DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
              value: dropdownValue,
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
              iconSize: 16,
              elevation: 10,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
              onChanged: (String newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  dropdownValue = newValue;
                });
              },
              items: <String>[dropdownValue, names.toString()]
                  .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                    onTap: () {
                      print('selected: ${value}');
                    }
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: use `rep.length`

```
for (int j = 0; j < rep.length; j++) {
```

Step 2: use `...names` not `names.toString()`

```
items: <String>[dropdownValue, ...names]
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginApi {
  static Future<List<Map>> pes() {
    return Future.value([
      {"name": "a"},
      {"name": "b"},
      {"name": "c"}
    ]);
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidgetFrom extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetStateFrom createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetStateFrom();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetStateFrom extends State<MyStatefulWidgetFrom> {
  String dropdownValue = 'select...';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: LoginApi.pes(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List<String> names = new List();
          final rep = snapshot.data;
          dropdownValue = 'select...';
          for (int j = 0; j < rep.length; j++) {
            names.add(rep[j]['name']);
          }
          return DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
            value: dropdownValue,
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
            iconSize: 16,
            elevation: 10,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
            onChanged: (String newValue) {
              setState(() {
                dropdownValue = newValue;
              });
            },
            items: <String>[dropdownValue, ...names]
                .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value),
                  onTap: () {
                    print('selected: ${value}');
                  });
            }).toList(),
          );
        }
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            MyStatefulWidgetFrom(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, please tell me about (...names)  if possible.

Comment: please reference https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-using-triple-dot-spread-operator-examples